# How to run a powershell script from Azure ADO pipeline as a different\admin user

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

We are building a scheduled pipeline in Azure ADO to shrink FSlogix profiles on Azure ANF shares.
Only our admin account have access to shrink those profiles. we are trying to run the pipeline on self hosted agents but it fails with below error.

"*Disk.ps1' cannot be run because it contains a "#requires" statement for running as
Administrator. The current Windows PowerShell session is not running as Administrator. Start Windows PowerShell by

using the Run as Administrator option, and then try running the script again.*"

I have put below piece of code in the script

```
$username = "username"

$password = password

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
```

and executing as inline script in azure pipeline powershell task

steps:

```
- task: PowerShell@2

  inputs:

   filePath: FslogixScript\Disk.ps1

   arguments: -RunAs -Credential $Cred -Path ......
```

Need a way to run this script with the specified user ID.

Comment: You cannot create a `PSCredential` object with a plain text password, you need to convert it to a `SecureString` first.

Comment: I have converted password to securestring, still same issue.

Comment: are `-RunAs` and `-Credential` supposed to be PowerShell arguments? Because I can't find those in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1). [This article](https://blog.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html) might help as well.